# Having a number at the end of a file and increasing it by 1 each time (with Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, game-development, pixi.js

My JS file creates this image and adds it to a folder.

```
'writenewimage_'+objId+'.png';
```

Currently 'writenewimage_'+objId+'.png' just keeps getting replaced/overwritten, which isn't ideal. objId is "1".

What I'd like is for that number "1" at the end of the image name to increase by 1. So that each time the code is executed it adds a different new image to the folder. 'writenewimage_1','writenewimage_2','writenewimage_3' etc.

Would super appreciate any help! I'm a newbie to Javascript and this would be very helpful to learn. :)

Here is the code that includes this file:

```
Echomap_LoaderCCG.prototype.processDataToGame = function (gameActor, dataActor) {
    Echomap.Utils.log('processDataToGame', 'Called');
    //Echomap.Params.CCGData = {};
    var faPath  = Echomap.CCGUtil.getFacesPath();
    var tvPath  = Echomap.CCGUtil.getTVPath();
    var svPath  = Echomap.CCGUtil.getSVPath();

    var objId   = Echomap.Utils.getActorIdFromActor(gameActor);
    var objName = gameActor._name;
    Echomap.Utils.log('processDataToGame','objId',   objId);
    Echomap.Utils.log('processDataToGame','objName', objName);

    gameActor.isComposite = undefined;
    gameActor.composite = {};
    gameActor.composite.filename = {};
    gameActor.composite.filename.face = faPath + 'writenewimage_'+objId+'.png';
    gameActor.composite.filename.tv   = tvPath + 'writenewimage_'+objId+'.png';
    gameActor.composite.filename.sv   = svPath + 'writenewimage_'+objId+'.png';
```

If it's confusing or you need more code than this, let me know! There might be some more I need to show, I'm not sure, but I don't wanna overwhelm you all with anything that might be irrelevant. I'm a bit of a noob with JS and trying to get my head around it. Just wanna try and increase "writenewimage_1"s number by 1 each time so they can be separate files if possible rather than have it keep overwriting the same file. ^_^

Comment: Please provide the code you have.

Comment: Alright. I'll update the post so it includes it. There is thousands of lines of code here so I'll try and make sure I just include the relevant parts.

Comment: I believe it's pixi.js. I've added it as a tag. ^_^

Comment: I would suggest to generate uuid (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) instead of just incremeting ids to prevent overwriting of files.